# Disable IPv6 for python script

Tags: python, ipv6

I'm looking for a generic way to suppress AAAA resolution within one specific python script. Is there an easy way to do that?

I use the Youtube Data API for python which is using httplib2 for the handshake stuff. I guess I would need something lowlevel like socket overrides or something.

The problem the domain to lookup is a google domain and therefore working with the IPv6 preference options for specific prefixes won't work.

The underlaying problem is that my IPv6 address is currently geo located in Iraq which is wrong... I already filed a request to fix that but would like to run the script in the meantime.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your script is doing? In fact, could you post a [small, self contained, working example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem? As the question is currently phrased, it's nearly impossible to answer, as we don't know what modules or libraries your script is using, whether it's calling out to external programs, or anything of the sort.

Comment: I'm using httplib2 to authenticate against the YouTube Data API. The problem is that the IPv6 lookup is happening and seems to be prefered my default. I'm looking for a generic --disable-ipv6 flag that I can invoke in runtime to suppress IPv6 lookups.

Comment: I used the [gai.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gai.conf "gai.conf") method to decrease the preference for the whole /32 IPv6 prefix. Was good enough for my usecase.

Comment: Do you have administrator access to your machine. You could turn off IPV6 on the machine and then run the script.

Comment: I think it would be better to fix the actual network issue.

Answer (score 10):

There is no global Python switch for this, nor does `httplib2` appear to provide any way to control it.

`httplib2` uses [`socket.getaddrinfo`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) (see the source of [`httplib2.HTTPConnectionWithTimeout.connect`](https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/blob/master/python2/httplib2/__init__.py#L879)) to look up the address to connect to based on the domain name. It passes `0` in as the family argument, which means use any available family.

So, to solve this, you need to have some way to override that. One way would be to implement your own connection class, let's call it `IPv4Connection`, that inherits from `httplib2.HTTPConnectionWithTimeout` or `httplib.Connection` and overrides `connect` to force it to use IPv4, then pass that in as the `connection_type` parameter when calling `Http.request(uri, connection_type=IPv4Connection)`.

Another would be to monkey-patch `socket.getaddrinfo` to force the family argument to always be `socket.AF_INET`.

Another would be to use an underlying way to get your C library to prefer IPv4 or disable IPv6. This will vary by platform, but on Linux using glibc you could edit [`/etc/gai.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gai.conf.5.html) to always prefer IPv4 over IPv6:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```